# Use AudioKit playgrounds with Xcode 10.2.1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, audiokit

I am trying to run AudioKit playgrounds in Xcode 10.2 but having no luck, probably due to wrong way when trying to update the AK version bundled with the playground.
I downloaded the playgrounds from AK downloads page and as playgrounds are seemingly not yet bundled with the newest AK version, it fails on build with `Module compiled with Swift 4.2.1 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.0.1 ...AudioKitPlaygrounds/AudioKitUI.framework/Modules/AudioKitUI.swiftmodule/x86_64.swiftmodule`.

I have tried removing and adding compiled AK+AKUI framework for MacOS on version 4.7.2 (which should be compiled for Swift 5) into the playground, but the build still fails with the same error on line with `import AudioKit` in AKPhoneView.swift file. Not sure if I am missing some other step or doing it completely wrong...

Side note: I am changing the AK and AK UI framework by removing the old and adding the new ones via Linked frameworks and libraries under the general tab. I also tried removing them from the Frameworks directory in the left Navigator bar (remove references).